# how to incorporate the "enter key" to a button press event

Tags: c, gtk

I've looked all over the place. Either I didn't look hard enough, or it is my lack of knowledge in C and GTK+. I am making a program similar to the program invoked when Alt+F2 is pressed. This is just for the learning experience. I have made a button called "button" in which you click it after typing in the program you want to run. I've been trying all day to program the button to also work when the "enter key" is pressed. Here is a part of my program responsible for invoking action to assigned widgets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget *entry;

static gboolean kill_window(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
    return FALSE;
}

static void button_press(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    const char *text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
    //system("cd" text);
    //printf("%s\n", text);
    const char *text2 = "&";
    char *concatenation;
    concatenation = malloc(strlen(text)+2);
    strcpy(concatenation, text);
    strcat(concatenation, text2);
    system(concatenation); 
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *hbox;


gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Run");
button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Cancel");
entry = gtk_entry_new();
hbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 2);

gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Run");

g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(kill_window), NULL)

g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_press), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(kill_window), NULL);
gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 100);
gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 2);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button, FALSE, FALSE, 2); 
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button1, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), hbox);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main(); 

return 0;
```

}

All I need now is to get "button" to be invoked when pressing the "enter key". (Sorry if i sound redundant.)

Comment: try to add `g_signal_connect(entry, "activate", G_CALLBACK(button_press), NULL);` (Sorry I cant check it right now)

Comment: Sweet! It works! Just wondering though.. why do we have to connect to to "entry" eather than "button" ??

Comment: The focus is on entry when you press Enter. So entry handles the events.

Comment: Don't mean to be a nuisance, but can you explain a bit further?

Comment: The cursor in in the entry. So the entry has the focus (it is active element for now). And the focused items fires the signals (so when you press enter, your GTK+ button does not have focus, and does not fire signal). There is a way to capture global signals, ex when Arrow button is pressed on the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

So as I see you need to add "Enter Button" signal handler to the text box, not to the button.

Try to add

```
g_signal_connect(entry, "activate", G_CALLBACK(button_press), NULL);
```

(Sorry I cant check it right now)

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the [activate](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate) signal of your entry, and have the callback do the same as your button click handler.

```
   g_signal_connect(entry, "activate", G_CALLBACK(button_press), NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a dialog like this GTK provides the concept of a default widget which is activated when you press Enter on any GtkEntry that has the `activates-default` property set to true. There is no need to explicitly connect a signal and the default widget is highlighted so the user can see which button will be activated when they press enter. To set it up add the following

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (button), "can-default", TRUE, "has-default", TRUE, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (entry), "activates-default", TRUE, NULL);
/* Could do this instead of the second g_object_set 
   gtk_entry_set_activates_default (GTK_ENTRY (entry), TRUE); */
```

You could also use [gtk_button_new_from_stock](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-new-from-stock) rather than gtk_button_new. You might want to check out [g_spawn_command_line_async](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-command-line-async) as well.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but capturing the "enter key" in C. Is done in the following way.

```
int enter_key = getch(stdin);

if(enter_key == '\r')
{
    //Do whatever is necessary.
}
```

The '\r' is called a carriage return and can also be referenced using it's [octagonal](http://www.asciitable.com/) value '\015'. Also a newline('\n' '\012') may be returned instead of a carriage return so you might want to do the following instead.

```
if(enter_key == '\r' || enter_key == '\n')
{
   //Do whatever is necessary
}
```

Comment: This won't do, as the task is to capture the enter key in a GUI widget.